# Change the format/style of existing code in Visual Studio; is it possible?

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, automated-refactoring

I have searched up and down for this, but allthe answers I find are for changing the auto formatting options Visual Studio for new code. I'm wonder if it is possible to change the format of existing code. For example:

```
if(myboolean)
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
```

becomes:

```
if(myboolean) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a built in feature that does this that I am missing, or perhaps some extension that does this that anyone can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

For vs2012 is Tools / Options / Text Editor /All languajes/ Tabs and then you should to select (None, block or smart). Also you can choose the size of tabs.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165330(v=vs.100).aspx. I hope this helps.

Comment: This is for new code; I am asking for a feature to refactor the formatting of EXISTING code.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl + K, then press Ctrl + D to format existing code in Visual Studio.

You can also use Edit->Advanced to access several options relating to formatting existing code in Visual Studio.